# API Gateway -> SQS HTTP POST MessageAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I have an API gateway setup which sends to SQS which fires a Lambda, I am trying to pass message attributes to the SQS but when I hit the endpoint in postman I keep getting a 400 Bad Request.. what is the right way to send the attributes over a JSON POST body

here is body from postman (have tried a few options based on [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-metadata.html#sqs-message-attributes))

```
    "message": "Message",
   "MessageAttributes": {
    "Name": "Name",
      "Type": "String",
      "Value": "my value"
    
   }
}
```

Here is how API Gateway is configured

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone stumbles on this later here is worked from the CDK side

```
let intergation = new apiGateway.CfnIntegration(this, 'Integration', {
      apiId: props.httpApi.httpApiId,
      payloadFormatVersion: '1.0',
      integrationType: 'AWS_PROXY',
      credentialsArn: apigwRole.roleArn,
      integrationSubtype: 'SQS-SendMessage',
      requestParameters: {
        QueueUrl: sqsqueue.queueUrl,
        MessageBody: '$request.body',
        MessageAttributes: '$request.body.MessageAttributes'
      }
    })

    new apiGateway.CfnRoute(this, 'Route', {
      apiId: props.httpApi.httpApiId,
      routeKey: apiGateway.HttpRouteKey.with('/url/foo', apiGateway.HttpMethod.POST).key,
      target: `integrations/${intergation .ref}`
    }).addDependsOn(intergation);
```

and the cloudformation

```
 MessageBody: $request.body
 MessageAttributes: $request.body.MessageAttribute
```

then in post man the POST body content type as application/json

```
{
   "message": "Message",
   "MessageAttributes": {
    "Attributes": {
      "DataType": "String",
      "StringValue": "my value"
    }
   }
}
```

the lamba would log out both separate for each Record from the event body

```
    Records: [
    {
     ....
      body: 'Message',
      attributes: [Object],
      messageAttributes: [Object]
  
    }
  ]
}
```

the messageAttributes object from above:

```
    {
  Attributes: {
    stringValue: 'my value',
    stringListValues: [],
    binaryListValues: [],
    dataType: 'String'
  }
}
```

This is using AWS API Gateway v2 HTTP API also